# Get canvas from context

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Is there any way to obtain the canvas that a context is used for?

Why I'm asking is because I'm creating a prototype function for `CanvasRenderingContext2D` in which I need the width/height of the canvas element.

E.g.:

```
var cv = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = cv.getContext('2d');
// Using only 'ctx', how to get 'cv'?
```

Comment: to get the id of the canvas, use ctx.canvas.width and ctx.canvas.height to get the current canvas size, ctx.canvas.id gives you the assigned ID of the canvas context you are working on.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`ctx.canvas` should return the canvas DOM node, from which you can get height and width.

I tried it with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_usage

Firefox was able to return ctx.canvas, as well as ctx.canvas.width and ctx.canvas.height. Also confirmed in Chrome.

Comment: This is [part of the specs](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-canvas).

Comment: link rot. This is the reason why you shouldn't just give a link, but also summarise it.

Comment: @Volodya - `ctx.canvas should return the canvas DOM node` *is* the summary.

Comment: New location for the rotted page is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_usage. Suggesting edit now.

Answer (score 4):

Try this to check for yourself:

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var isSameObject = canvas === context.canvas;

alert(isSameObject
    ? 'context.canvas gives expected result'
    : 'unexpected result');
```

[Here's the above in a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drewnoakes/ftqVE/).